# How to form this Matrix?

Tags: matrices

A chemist wish to mix 
**67ml chem-A, 48ml chem-B, and 32ml chem-C**
into **5000ml** of water.

One bottle of **brand I** product would contain
**7ml A, 5ml B, 1ml C**,

one bottle of **brand II** would contain 
**3ml A, 2ml B and 2 C,**

while **brand III : 4ml A, 3ml B, 3ml C,**

How many bottles of brand I , brand II, and brand III does the chemist need to get the required mixture?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i don't even know how to form the matrix, i usually would try my question first

Comment: Did you write equations ? If you did, add them to the post.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici can you give me some clues first? do i make chemicals into x y z? then what about the brands?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Brand I+II+III=5L?
67x+48y+32z=5000?

Answer (score 0):

P = [7; 5; 1]

Q = [3; 2; 2]

R = [4; 3; 3]

P, Q, R matrices are column matrices representing brands I, II, III respectively.

So, Px + Qy + Rz = M

where x, y, z are number of bottles of brands I, II, III required to get the mixture.

and M = [67; 48; 32] is the column matrix representing the content of mixture.

There are 3 linear equations here written in the form of matrices.